# Show null results when left join don't find match

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have problem with join left. It work fine but i don't see null results. It connects three tables - categories, product_categories and order_products.

Query made by stack user look's like:

```
       SELECT
categories.name,categories.id,
SUM((orders_products.product_price_gross + orders_products.option_price)*(1 - (orders_products.rebate/100))  * orders_products.product_qty) as suma
FROM orders_products
LEFT JOIN product_categories
ON product_categories.product_id = orders_products.product_id
LEFT JOIN categories
ON product_categories.category_id = categories.id
GROUP BY categories.name, categories.id
ORDER BY suma DESC
```

I'm not sure how upgrade  this query - I need to see what never been sold to show  on shop statistics.

I hope You could help me.

Kind regards 
Mark

Comment: MySQL does not support FULL OUTER JOIN

Comment: opps - sorry wrong  copy and paste :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to see products that has not been sold? Your main table is the transaction table `orders_products`. So any product not "ordered" will not show. Interchange `product_categories` and `orders_products` to achieve what you want. This will list all categories and null out the "suma" if JOIN statement cannot find the `product_id` listed in the "order_products" table

```
SELECT
    categories.name,
    categories.id,
    SUM((orders_products.product_price_gross + orders_products.option_price)*(1 - (orders_products.rebate/100))  * orders_products.product_qty) AS suma
FROM product_categories
LEFT JOIN orders_products 
    ON product_categories.product_id = orders_products.product_id
LEFT JOIN categories
    ON product_categories.category_id = categories.id
GROUP BY categories.name, categories.id
ORDER BY suma DESC
```

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and mark this as answer if this solved your problem. Glad I could help :)

Comment: Thanks for answear.  Let me  explain a litte:  for example  we got 10 categories. Only 6 of 10  had some entries in order_products (we sold something and we store data in that table). If we don't sell  nothing from some (4 of 10)categories we don't have entries  in  orders_products. Problem is when join is looking for coresponding rows in order_products table. If he find  - query will return result but if we don't have nothing there nothing will be displayed. We wan't to see what never been sold.

Comment: Did you try out the query i answered? that is suppose to give you what you just explained.

Comment: Well i jsut tested it. It hangs database for some reason.  Maybe to much data? I've got about 2500 categories,  16000 products and a lot of order_products entries?

Comment: I found problem. No index on  orders_product.product_id I add and query works perfect. 1.78s avg :)! Many thanks!